# Differential equation solution using Method of undetermined coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Finding solution of differential equation $y''-5y'+6y=5t^2-5\sin(3t)+9te^{2t}$ using method of undetermined coefficients.

What I try :: let $y=y_{c.f}+y_{p}$ be the solution of the above differential equation.

Now for finding complementary function.

Substitute $$(D^2-5D+6)y=0\Longrightarrow (D-2)(D-3)y=0$$

So we have $D=2,D=3$

So its complementary function $$y_{c.f}=C_{1}e^{2t}+C_{2}e^{3t}$$

Now I am not be able to find particular integral $(y_{p})$ using undetermined coefficients.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: The particular solution should be of the form $y_p= At^2 +Bt+ C + D\cos(5t) +E\sin(5t) + F e^{2t} + G te^{2t} + Ht^2e^{2t}.$

Comment: @Mick : The term with $F$ is part of the complementary solution, so $F=0$ can be chosen for the particular one.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

Its better to split the differential equation in three;
$$y''-5y'+6y=5t^2$$
$$\implies y_p=At^2+Bt+C$$
$$y''-5y'+6y=5\sin(3t)$$
$$\implies y_p=A \sin (3t)+B\cos (3t)$$
$$y''-5y'+6y=9te^{2t}$$
$$\implies y_p=t(At+B)e^{2t}$$

Comment: Thanks Lutz Its corrected. @LutzLehmann

Comment: True @LutzLehmann Thanks a lot.